# C# WinForms - Real (including non-client) FixedToolWindow height and width

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to place a fixed tool window in the bottom right portion of my primary screen just above the start menu bar.
I'm using the following code

```
this.Top = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Bottom - this.Height;
this.Left = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Right - this.Width;
```

The form aligns the edge of the screen to the client rectangle so I see the non client bottom edge bleed into the start menu bar and the right non client edge bleed into the second monitor.

I need to get the full form width and height including all the non client borders

I notice it works when the form is SizableToolWindow but not with FixedToolWindow

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Your code seems to be working perfectly here. Where are you calling it from?

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 w/ Aero, I call the code on shown, and resize.

Comment: I just realized, it only happens when the FormBorderStyle is FixedToolWindow, it works fine when it's SizableToolWindow

Comment: Hmm yes, pretty interesting behaviour tough, it also seems in error when using FixedDialog. It all works ok tough in classic skin wich also has a slimmer frame.

Comment: The answer is here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/af2608c1-1159-444f-bb21-b2cf0228f1c1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hans got this answer right but posted it as comment instead of an answer.

> The answer is here:
>   https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/af2608c1-1159-444f-bb21-b2cf0228f1c1/strange-issues-with-formborderstyle-on-vista-between-fixed-and-sizable-modes?forum=winforms
>   – Hans Passant May 19 at 21:07

Copied from site:

**Strange issues with FormBorderStyle on Vista between fixed and sizable modes**

Question:

The problem lies on all types of fixed border styles like FixedDialog, Fixed3D, FixedSingle and FixedToolWindow. It does not happen on the sizable ones. This problem, like I said, also happens only on Vista.
Let's say you have a form with any of the fixed border styles and set the starting location to 0,0. What you want here is for the form to be snapped to the top left corner of the screen. This works just fine if the form border style is one of the sizable options, if it's fixed, well, the form will be a little bit outside of the screen working area both to the left and top.
What's more strange about this is that the form location does not change, it sill is 0,0, but a few pixels of the form are drawn outside of the working screen area.
I tested this on XP and it didn't happen, the problem is Vista specific. On XP, the only difference was the border size that change a bit between any of the styles. But the form was always perfectly snapped to position 0,0.
If possible, without finding how many pixels are being drawn outside of the working area and then add that to the form location, is there a possible way to fix or workaround this?

Answer:

The problem is specific to Aero, it doesn't happen when you turn it off.  It is one of those famous app-compat fixes.  Windows actually lies to you when you P/Invoke GetWindowRect().  It gives window position and size, relative from the client area, that the window would have if it were running on an earlier version of Windows, like XP.

That makes sure that older programs still behave somewhat predictably, they'll have their all-important client area in the same location, even though they have much fatter borders.  But gets in the way at times, like your case.

To fix that, you have to convince Vista that you are really aware how Vista works.  That requires patching the .exe header.  Start the Visual Studio Command Prompt, navigate to your build directory and type this command:

editbin /subsystem:windows,6.0 yourprogram.exe

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/af2608c1-1159-444f-bb21-b2cf0228f1c1/  is the full link and will work.

Answer (score 2):

The `Bounds` property will give you a `Rectangle` from which you can get the full size.

> The bounds of the control include the nonclient elements such as scroll bars, borders, title bars, and menus.

[Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.bounds.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the comment from Hans correctly told us why the form's `.Height` and `.Width` are not correct.  I think the following should work to give you the real height and width, whether or not Aero is enabled.

```
(in the code for a Form)

[DllImport("dwmapi.dll", PreserveSig = false)]
public static extern bool DwmIsCompositionEnabled();

// When Aero is enabled, and our FormBorderStyle is FixedToolWindow,
//    Windows will lie to us about our size and position.
public bool AeroIsMessingWithUs()
{
    bool ret = false;

    // check for other Fixed styles here if needed
    if (FormBorderStyle == System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow)
    {
        if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6 && DwmIsCompositionEnabled())
        {
            // Aero is enabled
            ret = true;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

public int MyWindowHeight()
{
    int height = Height;
    if (AeroIsMessingWithUs())
    {
        // there are actually 5 more pixels on the top and bottom
        height += 10;
    }
    return height;
}

public int MyWindowWidth()
{
    int width = Width;
    if (AeroIsMessingWithUs())
    {
        // there are 5 more pixels on the left and right
        width += 10;
    }
    return width;
}
```